# Automatization of javascript building

Tags: javascript, makefile, google-closure-compiler, rakefile

I want to use Google Closure Compiler(GCC further) for joining my js-files and compressing before deploy. It's ok, if I will need to run some script. But how can I write a file with options for GCC? I can only write a *.sh file with task.

Help me please. Also it will be great, if there is some tool, that can watch for changes in my local `js` folder and run that task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are lots of "make" systems that provide a command to rebuild your software according to a set of rules when one of the source files changes. GNU/Linux has make, Java has ant, CoffeeScript has cake, Ruby has rake, etc. Any of these can spawn a task that will compile your .js files. They *all* have fiddly syntax.
2. A system that detects file changes and automatically rebuilds, tests, and deploys everything when files change is called a "continuous build", "continuous integration", or "continuous deployment" system. The big one is [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) developed for Java.

It sounds like you want a fairly simple single-user combination of 1 and 2.

node.js is well-suited to running a job that watches for file changes and spawns build commands. It doesn't have a "standard" JavaScript build system or continuous integration system. But there are lots of projects out there, such as

- [ready.js](https://github.com/dsimard/ready.js)
- drip for node.js got a lot of coverage but I'm not sure its status.
- the CoffeeScript language (that compiles into JavaScript) has a [Cakefile](http://coffeescript.org/#cake) system that can watch for script changes and run commands

I'm trying to decide between ready.js and Cakefile myself.

Answer (score 2):

check out plovr. http://plovr.com/

Comment: Seems like extremely useful stuff. Will check it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get node.js so you can write make files in javascript , that's the best way to do it.

Comment: you need to get the closure compiler package for node through npm then  the syntax is no more ugly than the classic makefile one , it is just javascript.

Comment: cool, but do you have some examples? I'm not node.js programmer, mostly specified on browser-side programming.

Comment: hi did install theclosurecompiler package with npm?